# escaping ruby values in hash

Tags: ruby, hashmap, escaping

I'm trying to use the values of other variable when declaring a ruby hash. Those values are now being escaped as I expected. How can I fix this?

**variables**

ipa_url, name, version and bundle-identifier

**code**

```
data = {
            plist: {
              dict: {
                key: 'items',
                array: {
                  dict: {
                    key: %w('assets','metadata'),
                    array: {
                      dict: [{ key:    %w('kind','url'),
                               string: %w('software-package',
                                          "#{ipa_url") },
                             { key:    %w('kind','url'),
                               string: %w('display-image',"#{icon_url.to_s}") },
                             { key:    %w('kind','url'),
                               string: %w('full-size-image',
                                          "#{icon_url}") }],
                      dict: { key: %w('bundle-identifier','bundle-version',
                                      'kind','title'),
                              string: %w("#{bundle-identifier}","#{version}",
                                         'software',"#{name}")
                      }
                    }
                  }
                }
              }
            }
          }
```

Comment: Are you sure you mean `%w('assets','metadata')`? Don't you really want `%w(assets metadata)` or `['assets','metadata']`?

Comment: When asking a question like this, reduce your data sample to the bare minimum necessary to effectively demonstrate the problem. Anything else beyond that slows down our ability to help you.

Comment: @AntarrByrd, If you really meant to use `%w(assets metadata)`, then fix your example to reflect that. Don't let it remain wrong and misleading.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `%w` identifier is used to created an array out of a space delimited text:

```
%w(this is a test)
# => ["this", "is", "a", "test"]
```

If you want to use string interpolation there, you should use `%W` instead:

```
variable = 'test'
%W(this is a #{variable})
# => ["this", "is", "a", "test"]
```

Answer (score 1):

[zenspider](http://www.zenspider.com/Languages/Ruby/QuickRef.html#4) goes over this in detail but for SO purposes, here's the breakdown:

**%q(no interpolation)**

```
[6] pry(main)> hey
=> "hello"
[7] pry(main)> hash = { 'hi' => %q("#{hey}", 'how are you') }
=> {"hi"=>"\"\#{hey}\", 'how are you'"}
```

**%Q(interpolation and backslashes)**

```
[8] pry(main)> hash = { 'hi' => %Q("#{hey}", 'how are you') }
=> {"hi"=>"\"hello\", 'how are you'"}
```

**%(interpolation and backslashes)**

```
[9] pry(main)> hash = { 'hi' => %("#{hey}", 'how are you') }
=> {"hi"=>"\"hello\", 'how are you'"}
```

**%W(interpolation)** as Uri showed:

```
[7] pry(main)> hash = { 'hi' => %W(#{hey} how are you) }
=> {"hi"=>["hello", "how", "are", "you"]}
```